# MIP/LP - Modelling “if distance(i,j)<=e then x=1” constraint

Tags: mathematical-modeling, constraints, mixed-integer-programming

I want to add a constraint to my model that works like this:

if distance(i,j)<=e then x=1

The distance(i,j) is calculated based on euclidean distance between a determined point and an undetermined point that its coordinate is continuous variable in my problem. x is a binary variable.

could anyone help me with my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a big-M constraint to enforce $d_{i,j} < e \implies x = 1$:
$$e - d_{i,j} \le M_{i,j} x,$$
where $M_{i,j}$ is a (small) upper bound on $e - d_{i,j}$.

To enforce $d_{i,j} > e \implies x = 0$, use another big-M constraint:
$$d_{i,j} - e \le (U_{i,j} -e) (1-x),$$
where $U_{i,j}$ is a (small) upper bound on $d_{i,j}$.

Comment: d is always nonnegative so upper bound on e−di,j can be e, so that when x=1, we have e−di,j <=e, which means di,j>=0. so that I think this constraint doesn't work correctly in this case. if   di,j>e, we have e−di,j <=e!!! It is not desirable...

Comment: Yes, $M_{i,j}=e$ looks like a good choice. If $d_{i,j}<e$, then the left hand side is positive, which forces $x=1$, as desired.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. I want if d(i,j)>e then x=0 too. but by the above constraint, if d(i,j)>e then x can get 0 or 1. how can I solve this problem?

Comment: I added the other direction just now.

Comment: Thanks so much.